# Alfresco Android SDK error during maven build

Tags: android, maven, sdk, alfresco

I've tried to download the sdk from alfresco github, but this is the error during mvn clean -DskipTests=true shell command
I'm obviously on Linux x64, 12.04 LTS.
Any clues?

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project
>   alfresco-mobile-android-client-api: Could not resolve dependencies for
>   project
>   org.alfresco.mobile.android.sdk:alfresco-mobile-android-client-api:jar:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT:
>   The following artifacts could not be resolved:
>   org.apache.chemistry.opencmis:chemistry-opencmis-android-client:jar:0.8.0-alfresco-patched,
>   org.alfresco.cmis.client:alfresco-opencmis-extension:jar:0.4-ANDROID-2:
>   Failure to find
>   org.apache.chemistry.opencmis:chemistry-opencmis-android-client:jar:0.8.0-alfresco-patched
>   in https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/public/ was cached in
>   the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the
>   update interval of apache-repository has elapsed or updates are forced
>   -> [Help 1]

Comment: Could you post the dependencies from your pom? It looks like you might not be depending on a suitable version

Comment: My pom is the default one downloaded from the github:
https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-android-sdk/blob/master/pom.xml
the same is happening with the Alfresco Android app:
https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-android-app/blob/master/pom.xml

Answer (score 2):

By default the master branch may contains some modified 3rd party dependencies. 
Those dependencies are not integrated inside the SDK project and don't have the same release lifecycle. So that's why publicly it's not possible sometimes to build the master branch.

Just before any release of the SDK, we publish all external dependencies. It's only at this time you can build the master branch.

If you want a stable version of the SDK, you have to use TAGS version of the github project.

Comment: fyi - I try to build TAG 1.2.0., but it also fails with an error: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project alfresco-mobile-android: Execution default-compile of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile failed: Unable to load the mojo 'compile' in the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1'. A required class is missing: org/codehaus/plexus/compiler/util/scan/InclusionScanException